# Windows Store App Collapse TextBlock if value is null using Style.xaml

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

If style definition is:

```
<Style x:Key="BodyTextStyle" TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaselineTextStyle}">
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiLight"/>
</Style>
```

How do I add property that would collapse the TextBlock if the value is null?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text,
               Converter={StaticResource TextIsNullOrEmptyToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

Then, create a `IValueConverter` named `TextIsNullOrEmptyToVisibilityConverter` which takes in a `string` and returns a `Visibility` enum based on `string.IsNullOrEmpty`.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Nate for his input.  The final solution is shown below.

First create the converter.

```
public class TextIsNullOrEmptyToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
public object IValueConverter.Convert(object value, System.Type targetType,   object parameter, string language)
    {
    string Str = (string)value;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Str)) {
        return Visibility.Collapsed;
    } else {
        return Visibility.Visible;
    }
}

public object IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
}
```

Give the converter a resource key in the page XAML file.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:TextIsNullOrEmptyToVisibilityConverter x:Key="visiblityConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

Apply the resource to the Visibility Attribute as by Nate above.

```
<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text,
           Converter={StaticResource TextIsNullOrEmptyToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```